# Find the parameter $a$ so the function is convex

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

Consider 
$$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, \: f(x) = x^2 - a |3x - 1| + 4, \: a \in \mathbb R$$

Find $a \in \mathbb R$ so that $f$ is convex on $[0, 1]$.

The answer is $(-\infty, 0]$.

I know that if a function is convex, that the second derivative is positive, which is the case here for all $x \in \mathbb R$. How come the answer is $(-\infty, 0]$ ?

Comment: Since $f'(1/3)$ is undefined, your second-derivative test will fail at $1/3$ (unless $a=0$), so you need some other way to handle that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that $f''(x)=2$ for any $x\not=1/3$, therefore $f$ is strictly convex in  $[1/3,+\infty)$ and  in $(-\infty,1/3]$. Unfortunately this does not imply that $f$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ (or in $[0,1]$ which contains $1/3$).

Note that $x^2+4$ and $|3x-1|$ are convex functions in $\mathbb{R}$ therefore if $a\leq 0$, then 
$$f(x) = x^2+4+ (- a) |3x - 1|$$
is a linear combination with non negative coefficients of convex functions  which implies that $f$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ for $a\leq 0$ (see the properties listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Convex_function_calculus)).

What about when $a>0$? Let's see what happens in a neighbourhood of $x=1/3$. We have that
$$f(1/3)-\frac{f(1/3-a)+f(1/3+a)}{2}=2a^2>0$$
which contradicts the [definition of convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition) 
$$\frac{f(1/3-a)+f(1/3+a)}{2}\geq f\left(\frac{(1/3-a)+(1/3+a)}{2}\right)=f(1/3).$$
Hence $f$ is not convex in any interval $[a,b]$ such that $a<1/3<b$.

Comment: I really don't know about this theory... what condition should I put, in general ?

Comment: @Liviu. Please see my edited answer. As I told you the problem here is the point $1/3$ and in order to verify the convexity you need the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition
Any further doubt?

Answer (score 1):

We need for all $\epsilon>0$ 
$$\frac{f\left(\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{3}-\epsilon\right)}{2}\geq f\left(\frac{\frac{1}{3}+\epsilon+\frac{1}{3}-\epsilon}{2}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$ or
$\epsilon(\epsilon-3a)\geq0$, which gives $a\leq0$.

Comment: Can you explain why,  please ?

Comment: @Liviu I fixed. See now please.